# EF6 - MySQL - Requiring ALL columns to be Non-Nullable

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I'm having some issues with creating an EDMX file in VX2013 using MySQL 5.7.7 Community version, EF 6.1.3, MySQL ADO Driver 6.9.8, MySQL Data Entities 6.8.3 and MySQL.Data.Entites 6.8.3.  When I try to create the model, I get error **13101: Key part 'internalfilename' for type 'property' is not valid.  All parts of the key must be non-nullable.**

I am creating all of my tables with an ID column that is Auto-Incremented, Primary Key and Not-Null.  I'm getting the above error on any table that I'm creating regardless of the number of columns I put in.

Is there anyway around this or any way to correct this problem?  I'd hate to think that every column I create will have to require a value.

Here's one table that I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE `property` (
`property_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`buyerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`buyeragent` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sellerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`selleragent` int(11) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`state` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`dateadded` datetime NOT NULL,
`internalfilename` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I should be using enough columns that even if EF wanted to create a composite key, it should be able to do so.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I reverted to MySQL Community Edition 5.6.27 and everything worked just fine with EF.

Comment: I also suffered from this error. I want to ask you 1 question. When You got "13101: Key part 'internalfilename' for type 'property' is not valid. All parts of the key must be non-nullable."  is your database was 'localhost'?

Comment: No.  I was using MySQL on the server that would be housing the production database.